# How to diagnose Azure AD B2C errors

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I have an Azure AD B2C app that is throwing an error after signing in.  How can I diagnose what is causing the error by accessing details of the error through Azure logs or the IDE?

This is what I see (edited to include the network traffic):

[image: Exception and network traffic]

The app is in Development mode and app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage() is being called in `Startup`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If B2C is going through its flow as you expect and the error is happening once it completes and returns to your app then the first/easiest thing to check is the network traffic in your browser's dev tools. Look for a call to the `/signin-oidc` endpoint in your app and see whether B2C returned an error or a token.

If it returned an error then that should give you some indication of what the error is and, if you've hooked B2C up to App Insights, it will give you a correlation ID that you can use to query log analytics.

If it returned a token then the problem is somewhere in your app, and *probably* not to do with B2C.

If it returned a code to exchange for a token then it could be your app or it could be the call to the token endpoint. I'd suggest making sure logging is set up in your app (e.g. to App Insights) and inspect what the result of the call to the B2C `/token` endpoint is.

You could also try adding event handlers to the OpenID Connect error events. How you do that may depend on your library, but there's usually a way to access an `Events` property on a configuration object which will likely have a standard set of events you can subscribe to.

Comment: Fantastic - thank you @Dave D!  That really helps me know where to focus.  I've updated the image to show the network traffic and it's looking all good, so the problem is with the app then.  I'll pursue that later today and post back here.  I very much appreciate your response :)

Comment: In the end, after hours more trying, I still couldn't work out what was happening! :(  So, as it was just an internal admin app, I switched to using a SQL identity store and got on with the rest of my day.

Comment: Sorry to hear that :( in your screenshot, the bit you're interested in is what was sent to the /signin-oidc endpoint. For example, in one of my successful sign-ins, when I click my /signin-oidc endpoint in Chrome's network tab I see `state`, `client_info`, and `code` in the Form Data section (because I'm using the OIDC code flow). Do you see something similar, maybe `id_token` instead of `code`, or do you see an error that B2C's sent instead?

Comment: I might come back to this later, Dave - just to see if I can get any further with it.  But, I've got rid of the B2C code and instance registrations after I got the EntityFramework setup working.  It took days of my life and I was very, very frustrating!